# Ubuntu Touch Apps

Tags: ubuntu-touch, skype, facebook

Is there a "native" Skype, Facebook, Google Maps, Google Hangouts, eBook Reader Apps being developed for Ubuntu Touch? If yes, whats their status? And if no, why? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking about some specific apps. Most of which have not yet been implemented. Why they haven't been imeplemented is largely due to connecting qml and javascript in with the apis that is provided by skype, googlemaps, facebook, twitter ect.

Firstly you can find out how to install the Ubuntu Touch core-apps and run them from [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2013/07/join-the-ubuntu-touch-core-apps-development-team/) and track their progress on the [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Collection)

Based on your question, I dont think Ubuntu Touch is at the stage you want it to be yet. It is still interesting to play around with the SDK and try out some of the other apps users have created though.

Comment: Ok, i understand that native apps are written in qml and webapps use html5/javascript/... But im not really a developer, i was just asking an ordinary user.
Based on your answer, it seems that its not possible right now to create a "native" Ubuntu Touch App for Skype/Facebook/Maps/... But is it technically possible to connect javascript with qml in order to have these apps?

Comment: Yep pretty close, javascript and c++ can be used for the logic but qml is generally used for the UI. Eventually there will be facebook, skype and twitter i'd say but Ubuntu Touch is still so young and has only had about 5 months of time for the community to work on this. Once some bigger businesses get on board after the platform becomes more streamlined you'll have plenty of apps

Comment: First link seems to be broken... Maybe [this](https://plus.google.com/communities/111350780270925540549) is the current equivalent?

Answer (score 6):

Current status (Sept 2015)

1. **Skype:** A [web app exists](https://uappexplorer.com/app/skype.peter-bittner) and provides Skype's original implementation available from [web.skype.com](https://web.skype.com), with messaging working but no voice and video calls yet. Skype/Microsoft are working on it. As soon as their web version fully works on Linux desktops it will work on Ubuntu Touch too. (Say hello to convergence!)
2. **Hangouts:** A [native app](https://uappexplorer.com/app/ubuntu-hangups.timsueberkrueb) is fresh in the making, it's called "Ubuntu Hangups" and uses an [Open Source library](https://github.com/tdryer/hangups) to access Google's proprietary protocol for instant messaging (no voice, no video calls). Messaging already works fine. Google's own implementation is available as a terrible, mostly useless web app. Google doesn't even care to make the web version responsive. (Shame on them!)
3. **Facebook:** No native app yet, but the [web app by Mitchell Reese](https://uappexplorer.com/app/facebook.mreese) (not the one by Canonical) works great. Most of the kudos must go to Facebook, of course.
4. **Google Maps** and other mapping apps: They work fine as web apps on Ubuntu Touch. Not bad, really, GPS flawlessly included. Just as in your web browser on the desktop.
5. **eBook Readers:** There's [a native app](https://uappexplorer.com/app/com.ubuntu.developer.rschroll.beru) that has quite a few fans, and convincing screenshots.